# Can it possible to put WCF and Web API in same solution sharing same service layer in c#?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

For one of project requirement we need web API and wcf services the business logic is common for both, so want to keep WEB API and WCF in same solution. Is this possible anyone have such type of thing Please help me in this.

Comment: Yes, you can. You just do it. What problem are you having putting these projects into a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible and one of the functionalities that architectures like Onion architecure/N-layer architecure/clean architecture provides.

Simple add a WebApi csproj and a Wcf csproj to your solution. Then add a businesslayer csproj to your solution. Then simply add a reference to your businesslayer project in your WebApi & Wcf Project.

Then just make sure to keep all business logic in the business layer classes and you are good to go.

From an architectural standpoint you will have the following structure

- Solution layer (WebApi & Wcf project) [both projects depends on Business logic
  layer]
- Business logic layer (Business layer csproj) [depends on
  nothing]

If you also read data from underlying databases, other APIs or files I would also suggest to add a bottom layer called the Data access layer (another csproj) where you do all data access like querying databases.

Then you will have something similar to this (arrows are dependencies):

[image]

One note: If you want to use Wcf togheter with .Net Core WebApi just make sure that BusinessLayer.csproj is a .net standard project so that you can run both. This is because WCF runs on .Net Framework.